# most of the time it says "Pending" and will not print. I went into Ubuntu and the Policies is Enabled...What else can I try?

Tags: printing

My 7520 Printer will not print unless I unplug the computer and printer....then it will print Sometimes!! Most of the time will not print it says "Pending" I went into Ubuntu Policies and it is ENABLED so that is not the problem  please help

Comment: If HP, I find I have to go into hp, hp device manager, printer control, & start printer. Not sure why it gets turned off.

Comment: as oldfred says, if you be willing to disclose on a public forum which make of printer you use, that could be helpful